# setting up a network adapter on ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu

Hi I am new to the networking domain.

I have recently bought a WLAN 11n USB adapter by a company named GMYLE.
I had difficulties setting up the same on my ubuntu environment.
The driver cd provided has instructions for installing it on ubuntu but I am finding the installation using command line really confusing.
I tried the GUI method myself.
I went to System->Administration->network tools but the device is not being listed out there?
Is there any specific reason for this?
Please help.
Is there an easier way (GUI method) which could help me in setting up the network adapter on my machine?

Any help would be sincerely appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you actually installed the driver? What files are on the CD? This page may be of some help, although it hasn't got a specific page for `GMYLE` cards. I must admit, I've never heard of this manufacturer.

Comment: This is off topic for SO, but may not be on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

While this is off-topic, here's something to help you:

The chipset the device uses is probably RTL8192cu. You can download the drivere [here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/searchView.aspx?keyword=RTL8192cu).

You can read about how to install it [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10656582&postcount=10) and [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=94495&f=53).